# DataContractSerializer using default properties

Tags: c#, .net, datacontractserializer

Recently when I read the default behavior of DataContractSerializer, I get the [rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656732(v=vs.110).aspx) from MSDN, however I do not understand the first rule which I extracted as below:

> The DataContractSerializer infers a data contract from types without attributes using the default properties of the newly created types.

How do I interpret this statement, if some one has clear idea, could you help, I know that "without attributes", the attribute means DataContract attribute, however what does that "default properties" refer to. Is there something called "default properties" in a custom type?

Comment: It means if you serialize a type that *doesn't* have a `DataContractAttribute`, it will look at the type and infer a contract. For the properties of that type it will use their default behaviors (so public properties will be serialized, for example and private ones won't - and names in the serialized output will be derived from the property names).

Comment: Thank you, Matt, this is clearly explained as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you a have type referenced within another class that has `[DataContract]` attribute, then DataContractSerializer will serialize the referenced type even if it is not attributed with `[DataContract]`. Serialization will happen on all public properties, unless the property is attributed with `[IgnoreDataMember]`.

For example:

```
[DataContract]
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassB MyData { get; set; }

    public string SomeString { get; set; }

    public int SomeNumber { get; set; }

}

public class ClassB
{
    public string SomeOtherInfo { get; set; }

    public int SomeOtherNumber { get; set; }
}
```

In the above code, ClassB will be serialized based on its default properties, which in this case are all the public properties: "SomeOtherInfo" and "SomeOtherNumber".